# proof by CP$ \binom{m}{1} S_{1}(n)+\binom{m}{2} S_{2}(n)+\binom{m}{3} S_{3}(n)+ \cdots +\binom{m}{m-1} S_{m-1}(n)=(n+1)^m-(n+1)$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

> Given a nonnegative integer $n$ and a positive integer $m$. How to prove
>   \begin{align}
> & \binom{m}{1}   S_{1}(n)+\binom{m}{2}  S_{2}(n)+\binom{m}{3}  S_{3}(n)+  \cdots +\binom{m}{m-1}  S_{m-1}(n) \\
> & =(n+1)^m-(n+1)
> \end{align}
>   where
>   $S_{k}(n) = 1^{k}+2^{k}+\cdots +n^{k}$ for all nonnegative integers $k$ ?

If $m = 2$, then this boils down to the little Gauss formula $2 S_1(n) = (n+1)^2 - (n+1)$. If $m = 3$, then this becomes $3 S_1(n) + 3 S_2(n) = (n+1)^3 - (n+1)$, which is easily proved by induction. Induction works for each given $m$, but what about a general proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M$ be a set with cardinality $m$, and let
$$
N:= \Bigl\{ \{a_1^1\};\{a_1^2;a_2^2\};\{a_1^3;a_2^3;a_3^3\} \dots \{a_1^n;a_2^n; \dots;a_n^n\}\Bigr\},
$$
where $a_{n_1}^{n_2} = a_{n_3}^{n_4} \iff (n_1 = n_3 \wedge n_2 = n_4)$.
(We can see that $|N| =n$).

Of course $S_k(1) = 1^k$ is the number of functions from a set of cardinality $k$ to the set of cardinality $1$. Generally $S_k(n)$ is the sum of number of functions from a set of cardinality $k$ to sets of cardinality $1,2,\dots, n$.

Notice that whenever $N'$ is an element of $N$ of cardinality $p$ and $M'$ is a subset of $M$ of cardinality $k$ there are $p^{k}$ functions from $M'$ to $N'$. Whence there are ${ m \choose k} p^k$ functions from any subset of $M$ of cardinality $k$ to $N$' (because we can choose a subset of $M$ in ${m \choose k} $ ways), which implies there are 
$${ m \choose k} \bigl(1^k +2^k +3^k + \dots + n^k\bigr)$$
functions from any $M' \subset M$ to any element of $N$, or just $${ m \choose k} S_k(n).$$

Lets sum the above equality from $k=1$ to $k=m-1$ and we'll get the LHS of subject equality. In other words, there are
$$
\binom{m}{1}   S_{1}(n)+\binom{m}{2}  S_{2}(n)+\binom{m}{3}  S_{3}(n)+  \cdots +\binom{m}{m-1}  S_{m-1}(n)
$$
partial functions $f:M \to N' \in N$ such that $ 1 \leq card\bigl(dom(f)\bigr) \leq m-1$ (for all $N' \in N$ taken together).

Consider now any element $N'$ of $N$. If $|N'| = p$ and $M'$ is a subset of $M$ of cardinality $m-1$ then there are $$(p+1)^{m} -1 - p^{m}$$ (non empty) partial functions from $M'$ to $N'$. (The $(-1 -p^k)$ term is because we should only admit functions with $1 \leq card\bigl(dom(f)\bigr) \leq m-1$, and we need to substract it from the total number of partial functions from $M$ to $N'$). Summing from $p=1$ to $p=n$ we get that the number of partial functions (such that $ 1 \leq card\bigl(dom(f)\bigr) \leq m-1$) from $M$ to any element of $N$ (taken together)  is equal to
$$
\sum_{p=1}^n (p+1)^m - 1 - p^m = -n + \sum_{p=1}^n(p+1)^m-p^m = -n - 1 + (n+1)^m,$$
which is just RHS of subject equality.

P.S. English is not my first language, so I apologise if this is unclear in some places. I will try to answer any question concerning the above proof (if you have any).